# Unity check if button is empty and hide it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello! Im making a quiz game and I need you help.

Im getting questions and answers from server and I display them in game like this:

```
    questionText.text = results.Result[0].question;
    button1Text.text = results.Result[0].answer1;
    button2Text.text = results.Result[0].answer2;
    button3Text.text = results.Result[0].answer3;
    button4Text.text = results.Result[0].answer4c;
```

For some questions I have only 2 answers, and then 2 buttons are left empty, [looks something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIfnK.png)

I need to make some kind of checker for buttons, if button is empty it gets hidden, but if there is something in button it gets shown.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` to check if the answer is empty, for example like this:

```
questionText.text = results.Result[0].question;
button1Text.text = results.Result[0].answer1;
button2Text.text = results.Result[0].answer2;
button3Text.text = results.Result[0].answer3;
button4Text.text = results.Result[0].answer4c;

// Hide buttons if empty. So we invert the isNullOrEmpty (when it's true -> we do not want to show the button!)
// As corrected below by @dohavin. We take the parent of the text object, assuming that is the actual button object.
button1Text.transform.parent.gameObject.setActive(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(results.Result[0].answer1));
button2Text.transform.parent.gameObject.setActive(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(results.Result[0].answer2));
button3Text.transform.parent.gameObject.setActive(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(results.Result[0].answer3));
button4Text.transform.parent.gameObject.setActive(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(results.Result[0].answer4c));
```

Comment: This solution would just disable buttonText. To disable whole gameObject you need to apply this for button object, not text object

Comment: You are indeed correct. I will edit it to add `gameObject`.

Comment: Applied this method to GameObject, worked for me, thanks!